Pop os 22.04 LTS freezing randomly
edit: I'm guessing its the new NVIDIA version 555 that rolled out yesterday, I reverted it back to 550 and I'll be testing it for full day to see if it solves this.
it's Pop os 22.04 LTS, Gnome version 42.9.
(I really don't know what info is needed to help me here. If it keeps happening, I will update and keep this post up.)
I have been having this issue for some time now, ever since I fully updated my system with Cosmic Store. My whole screen plus mouse would freeze, but whatever was playing before the freeze still could be heard. It seems to freeze after 7 minutes from login.
I keep having to use the old kernel version, but it will freeze after 3+ hours or so.
The first time it froze, I used ctrl+alt+f3 to delete the gnome shell, which seemed to work... then it froze again after some minutes.
I installed smartmontools and my hard drive overall health is good, no errors logs.
used "dmesg" command, everything in kernel(?) seems fine.
doing the "journalctl -xe" command, the logs are all green.
Here's the result of the "journalctl -e | grep ERROR" command:
Jul 26 05:24:54 pop-os vesktop.desktop[5169]: [5169:0726/052454.161121:ERROR:vaapi_wrapper.cc(1585)] Could not get a valid VA display
Jul 26 05:24:54 pop-os vesktop.desktop[5169]: [5169:0726/052454.161217:ERROR:vaapi_video_decoder.cc(1212)] failed initializing VaapiWrapper for profile h264 high,

solved! I had NVIDIA driver issues, the 555 version rolled out before yesterday and caused problems, so I reverted back to version 550.
sudo apt purge ~nnvidia

sudo apt install nvidia-driver-550-server

sudo apt update

sudo dkms autoinstall

sudo reboot

